# Divert customer order to nearest seller with use of api in open cart mvc

Tags: php, opencart, e-commerce

I am working in multi seller ***open cart*** ***MVC***
my work is Divert customer order to nearest seller with use of api
i am store customer and seller address in customerorigin and sellerdestination 
only i find distance 
so how can i use google api code to find distance in open cart my code which is work correct in demo index page but when i use api method to open cart his show
hoe to find distance and after find how to store distance in data base
 a error my code and error is here :-
provide some code

Order.php in

$customerorigin = customer address get in data base
$sellerdestination = seller address get in data base

`$from = $customerorigin;
 $to = $sellerdestination;
$data = file_get_contents("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=$from&destinations=$to&language=en-EN&sensor=false");`

```
      $data = json_decode($data);
      $time = 0;
      $distance = 0;
  foreach($data->rows[0]->elements as $road) {
       $time += $road->duration->value;
       $distance += $road->distance->value;
      }`
```

Notice: Array to string conversion in 
Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$duration in 
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in 
Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$distance in 
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in INSERT INTO `oc_distance` VALUES (9,2,3,0)

Comment: Anurag: It is unclear what you are asking. Do take a few minutes to read our guides: [on-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think i got what the problem is , but there is no code to support that so i am going to write an implementation that i think you can use for the same.

First you need to get location of the customers.have a look at [geolocation](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp) for the same. That will return you the coordinates of your client in js.

Now i am assuming you have coordinates for store present in your database. You can use google api to find the distance between them or there is also a simple formula to calulate displacement but because of store i think that you will be more inclined towards distance which google maps has a neat api for.

hope this helps

Comment: @AnuragTripathi try var_dump on the result

Comment: I got answer put API code in where order place (function add_Order in model file)  and pass seller and customer address in API function and it return some value store value in table with custom ID.